# Placeholder in C# expression WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to use placeholders in C# expression? I have a expression for filtering records in a datagrid as follows:

```
    view.Filter = item =>
        {                
            OrdsRlsd vitem = item as OrdsRlsd;                

            if (vitem.OrderNo >= Convert.ToInt32(TxtCond1.Text) && vitem.OrderNo <= Convert.ToInt32(TxtCond2.Text))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
```

In this expression, the the comparison operators and the TxtCond1 and TxtCond2 values are dynamic. Can we use a placeholder for that?

Comment: placeholder? Can you explain what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: does external variable or even late bound resolved value will be a good placholder in your terms? For instance Func<string>? ` Func<string> resolveString = () => TxtCond1.Text; Convert.ToInt32(resolveString())`

Comment: In the expression, vitem.OrderNo, The OrderNo is the column in the database table. If a user want to filter the datagrid by DateRequired(which is selected from a combo box by the user), how can we pass this to the expression, something like vitem.DateRequired

Comment: @sony : you can create mapping associations of FilterType - ColumnName and then use Dictionary<string, string> or Dictionary<string, Func<string>> to resolve it in runtime using `Dictionary.Contains()`

Comment: @sll : I dont know how to that. Could you please show an example of the same?

Comment: @sony : still you need an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can pass those as `Func<string>` parameters. So say your function definition is like this

```
public void Filter(Func<string> string1, Func<string> string2)
{
var result = item =>
        {                
            OrdsRlsd vitem = item as OrdsRlsd;                

            if (vitem.OrderNo >= Convert.ToInt32(string1.Invoke()) && vitem.OrderNo <= Convert.ToInt32(string2.Invoke()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };  
}
```

Comment: Hi there, Could you please give more explanation about the same. I couldnt understand it.

Comment: What is the part I need to explain?